# Why am I getting different results in the python interpreter than I do in a program file?

Tags: python

I am iterating through a dictionary using python. I get different results when I run the same lines in the python command line interpreter than I do in my program file.

This is the dictionary I'm am iterating through:

```
[
  {
    'UserName': 'tdunphy',
    'SSHPublicKeyId': 'APKA5AODVC64ZX5MQAL3',
    'Status': 'Active',
    'UploadDate': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 24, 14, 55, 31, tzinfo=tzutc())
  },
  {
    'UserName': 'tdunphy',
    'SSHPublicKeyId': 'APKA5AODVC64XOP4SW6S',
    'Status': 'Active',
    'UploadDate': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 24, 15, 3, 52, tzinfo=tzutc())
  },
  {
    'UserName': 'tdunphy',
    'SSHPublicKeyId': 'APKA5AODVC642ZRWMQWE',
    'Status': 'Active',
    'UploadDate': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 24, 15, 4, 19, tzinfo=tzutc())
  }
]
```

---

In the command line I go:

```
ssh_keys_list = (client.list_ssh_public_keys(UserName=user_name)['SSHPublicKeys'])
for ssh_key in ssh_keys_list:
    ssh_key_id = ssh_key['SSHPublicKeyId']
    print(ssh_key_id)
```

And I get this result back:

```
APKA5AODVC64ZX5MQAL3
APKA5AODVC64XOP4SW6S
APKA5AODVC642ZRWMQWE
```

However if I run it from my program I get an error:

```
ssh_key_id = ssh_key['SSHPublicKeyId']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The lines are the same between the two, I copy/pasted from the command line interpreter into the file and ran it. Why would there by a difference?

Comment: If you restart your python interpreter and re run just the code you have here do you get the same output? I'm thinking you have accidentally assigned a new value to ssh_key_list.

Comment: check if ssh_keys_list is a list of strings or list of dictionaries.  seems ssh_keys_list is a list of strings

Comment: if it is a single string, then the for loop will iterate on the characters.  but here you are assuming that it is a list of dictionaries and are acting accordingly, which is why the error.

Comment: So is `ssh_key_list` supposed to be the list of dictionaries? Try to print the full dictionary in the script and from the command line and see if it really the same object. I suspect you are reading the data differently.

Comment: It's a list of dictionaries. The exact list of dictionaries that I am looping through is posted in the OP! :)

Comment: If I hardcode your list of dictionaries in my test script, it runs correctly with your code. Could you share how do you read it in your program file?

Comment: Funny. I just copied my code from this post into the file I had open in visual studio. Now it works!